# Seeking a web site or computer program to quickly find kvi'ot

Tags: calendar, technology

I have a fascination with various aspects of the Judaic calendar. One aspect I find fascinating is *kvi'ot*.

A *kvi'ah* is a 3 letter mnemonic (in some cases, a 2-letter mnemonic is used) to indicate the day of the week Rosh Hashannah starts, the type of year, and the day of week for 1st day of Passover. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar#Four_gates) for a somewhat more detailed explanation.)

I notice that some *kvi'ot* are quite rare. Offhand, it seems that the 7 *chaser* kvi'ah is the rarest (or close to it). This *kvi'a* causes the 1st day of Chanukah to fall on Friday. It looks like the next time this will occur is in 5784 (Gregorian 2023). I can't recall the last time this *kevi'ah* occurred.

Rather than manually scanning a historical calendar or typing in trial & error years into *Hebcal* to see if there's a match, I'm wondering if there is some online program or some way that I can develop a program that will provide a list of specific *kevi'ah* occurrences. For example, I'd like to input the *kevi'ah* and a number representing the number of occurrences or perhaps, input a start and end year range.

Is there anything like this, around, or can any "tecchie" out there provide pseudo code or an alogorithm?

Comment: How about the chart in the Tur?

Comment: @DoubleAA I saw this a while ago. Ideally, I'd like something online. If you can provide a link to this chart, I'd appreciate it. It's been a while since I viewed it. I'd need to view it again to see if this will really do the job.

Comment: Chanukah started on a Friday in 2000 http://www.hebcal.com/converter/?hd=25&hm=Kislev&hy=5761&h2g=1

Comment: The rarest Keviah is Thursday-355

Comment: @DoubleAA What did you use to determine the stat in your last comment?

Comment: The Tur table can be found by searching online http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1939 though the Pri Chadash's extended list corrects a few errors http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2274

Comment: My father once wrote a program for exactly this, and published a table in the Danish Jewish community's newsletter, *Jødisk Orientering*. Wonder if I can dig up the code...

Comment: Write a program to calculate the _kvi'ah_ of a given year, and run it in a loop for each year?  I have written such a program in at least three different languages, though it'd have to be modified slightly to return the _kvi'ah_ instead of a calendar.

Comment: A version (not perfect) in Java, at https://github.com/masalomon/jcal.java.  Depending on how "techie" you are, you'll need to play with it a bit to generate the output you want.  If you want a custom program, contact me directly and I'll try to work something out for you.

Comment: The rarest FWIW is actually הש פשוטה, or השא, with just eight of the 247 years. I have a list of the frequencies, but it doesn't help you for calculating which are which.

Comment: Hi @DonielF A list of the frequencies even in print, would be useful, for now. Can you provide a link? If not, perhaps, I can create a shared dropbox area in my dropbox for you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V81Av.png. Note that this is based on the Tur's chart that [@DoubleAA mentioned](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78314/seeking-a-web-site-or-computer-program-to-quickly-find-kviot?noredirect=1#comment234999_78314), not the Pri Chadash's version.

Comment: All of the frequencies are simply the number of times the year appears divided by 247, rounded to four decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any online resources for what you are seeking, but I happen to have created a helpful calendar in Excel, and have made the first 6000 years available as a Google Sheet [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GQw5RHfE3DVf_ZyYq2Ekj_6_u-Hdl2X-0H6UpsNwY7g).

For your purposes, you could use a COUNTIF formula on column I for the period you are interested in, which will return the number of years of that type in the given period.